# I can't get my pictures to load on Github? I also can't get my css on the websites?

Tags: github, image-uploading, github-for-windows

I have tried to upload my jpg and png files and I have the whole path set up on the website itself, it works when I just open it from my code editor but it won't on my github page. So I have tried

For the Readme I have this in code:

```
<div class="top-container">
  <img class="top-cloud" src="C:\Users\mkouk24\Documents\Web Development\CSS-My Site\Images\cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
  <img class="bottom-cloud" src="C:\Users\mkouk24\Documents\Web Development\CSS-My Site\Images\cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
  <img src="C:\Users\mkouk24\Documents\Web Development\CSS-My Site\Images\mountain.png" alt="mountain-img">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="middle-container">
  <div class="profile">
    <img class="profile-picture" src="C:\Users\mkouk24\Documents\Web Development\CSS-My Site\Images\thumbnail2.jpg" alt="matthews profile picture">
    <img class="lightning" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/vt2UahsYgKKIg/giphy.gif" alt="lightning">
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="skills">
    <h2>My Skills.</h2>
    <div class="skill-row">
      <img class="martial-arts" src="C:\Users\mkouk24\Desktop/martial-arts.jpg" alt="martial-arts">
      <img class="gif" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7btNhMBytxAM6YBa/giphy.gif" alt="matrix">
    </div>
    <div class="skill-row">
      <img class="matrix-code" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/10zxDv7Hv5RF9C/giphy.gif" alt="matrix-code">
    </div>
  </div>
```

but when I commit the changes the pictures won't show although my gifs will show so am I doing something wrong or is there something I'm missing that I don't know about? I also have the html file which is pretty much the same but only it has the whole project in it's entirety, I have the css files in it as well but they won't show up either and my website just looks bare?

Comment: `C:\Users\mkouk24\...whatever` won't show up anywhere except on your local computer

Comment: What's your github repo?

Comment: https://github.com/mattk24/Main-Site.git

Comment: The absolute URL to your cloud image would be `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mattk24/Main-Site/master/cloud.png`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're hard-coding the image paths from your windows PC, Github will probably not be able to reach "C:\Users\mkouk24\Documents\" on your PC

to overcome that, just use the image path relative to the root of the website, example:

```
    <div class="top-container">
  <img class="top-cloud" src="Images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
  <img class="bottom-cloud" src="Images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
  <img src="Images/mountain.png" alt="mountain-img">
</div>
```

Comment: I've done that first but it still didn't go through so I tried to use the whole path way and it still didn't work?

Comment: Notice that I switched from windows path separators "\" to "/" as well that could be it. you can also share a link to your github URL

Comment: Do I put the github URL before or after the image tag?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out I had to download the picture and copy the it's git hub url